# Applying a function for a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python

I have a multi-index dataframe that is indexed by date and stock. Here is an example:

```
                     Column1
Date        Ticker
2008-08-01  AAPL     value1
            MSFT     value2
            IBM      value3
            etc.
2008-08-02  AAPL     value4
            MSFT     value5
            IBM      value6
            etc.
```

What I am trying to do is apply a function to this column for each date, and then replace that column. For example, say for each date, starting with 2008-08-01, I want to the average of Column1 and take the difference between each ticker's value and this average. And then Column1 will be replaced by these values. I'd end up having:

```
                     Column1
Date        Ticker
2008-08-01  AAPL     avg(Column1, 8/1/08) - value1
            MSFT     avg(Column1, 8/1/08) - value2
            IBM      avg(Column1, 8/1/08) - value3
            etc.
2008-08-02  AAPL     avg(Column1, 8/2/08) - value4
            MSFT     avg(Column1, 8/2/08) - value5
            IBM      avg(Column1, 8/2/08) - value6
            etc.
```

I can achieve this by doing:

```
df = df.copy()
col1_adjusted = [func(df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Date') == date]['Column1']) for date in dates]
col1_adjusted = [item for sublist in col1_adjusted for item in sublist]
df.Column1= col1_adjusted
```

But that takes a long time because I have a lot of dates. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should think of split-apply-combine. Split the data, calculate the average and subsequent subtraction and then join it back to form the required DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debasish is right about the split-apply-combine approach. For a simple example:

```
# Use groupby to find the average by date; sub in w/e func for mean    
df['Column2'] = df.groupby(level='Date').transform('mean')

# Replace Column1 with the desired value
df['Column1'] = df['Column2'] - df['Column1']
```

The above example was for clarity, but here is the better, one-liner:

```
df['Column1'] = df.groupby(level='Date')['Column1'].transform('mean').sub(df['Column1'])
```

Comment: Hey - if this answered your question, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I am still new here and didn't know. It did answer my question thank you!